# In React, how to show data from API in a HTML table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to display data from my example API. At the moment I'm able to loop through the array, and display all the titles, for example:

```
EventTitle1
EventTitle2
EventTitle3
...
```

Here is my code:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
constructor() {
   super();
   this.state = {
      data: []
   }
}
 
componentDidMount() {
 var th = this;
 this.serverRequest = axios.get(this.props.source)
 .then(function(event) { 
     th.setState({
         data: event.data
     });
 })
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.serverRequest.abort();
}
 
render() {
 var titles = []
 this.state.data.forEach(item => {
    titles.push(<h3 className=”events”>{item.title[0].value}</h3> );
 })
 return (
    <div className=”container”>
      <div className=”row”>
         <div className=”col-md-6 col-md-offset-5">
             <h1 className=”title”>All Events</h1>
             {titles} 
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
 } 
}

ReactDOM.render(
   <App source=”http://localhost:8888/example/api/events" />, 
   document.getElementById(‘container’)
);
```

How could I create an HTML table, to display only the five latest event titles from the API (and later other data) inside the table?

For example:

```
return (
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Event title</th>
        <th>Event location</th> 
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>First event title {titles[0]} ?? </td> 
        <td>San Fran</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Second event title {titles[1]} ??</td> 
        <td>London</td> 
      </tr>
    </table>
);
```

Comment: Event location is not from the API?

Comment: Yes, that also comes from the API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an array of `<tr>` and add it into the table.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
constructor() {
   super();
   this.state = {
      data: []
   }
}
 
componentDidMount() {
 var th = this;
 this.serverRequest = axios.get(this.props.source)
 .then(function(event) { 
     th.setState({
         data: event.data
     });
 })
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.serverRequest.abort();
}
 
render() {
 const contents = this.state.data.forEach(item => {
      // change the title and location key based on your API
      return <tr>
        <td>{item.title}</td> 
        <td>{item.location}</td>
      </tr>
 })
 return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
         <div className="col-md-6 col-md-offset-5">
             <h1 className="title">All Events</h1>
             <table>
              <tr>
                <th>Event title</th>
                <th>Event location</th> 
              </tr>
                {contents}
            </table>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
 } 
}

ReactDOM.render(
   <App source="http://localhost:8888/example/api/events" />, 
   document.getElementById("container")
);
```

Comment: That's great. How do I limit it to displaying only the five latest?

Comment: Use `{contents.slice(0,5)}` instead of `{contents}` in the render.

Comment: @PraneshRavi it would be best to slice the array before even mapping it.

Comment: Not true. If you want rest of the value you don't need to run the `map` again. You can use the array from the cache and splice from it.

Comment: This line is wrong! It should use ".map" instead of ".forEach". forEach doesn't return anything.
`const contents = this.state.data.forEach(item => {`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the `slice` operator to get the first 5 elements of you array, and then directly use `map`.

There is also no need to use a `titles` array, you can just put the snippet inline in the jsx.

The important part of the code is:

```
<table>
    {data.slice(0,5).map(event => (<tr>
        <td>{event.title}</td>
        <td>{event.location}</td>
    </tr>))}
</table>
```

Here is the full example:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
constructor() {
   super();
   this.state = {
      data: []
   }
}
 
componentDidMount() {
 var th = this;
 this.serverRequest = axios.get(this.props.source)
 .then(function(event) { 
     th.setState({
         data: event.data
     });
 })
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.serverRequest.abort();
}
 
render() {
 return (
    <div className=”container”>
      <div className=”row”>
         <div className=”col-md-6 col-md-offset-5">
            <h1 className=”title”>All Events</h1>
            <table>
               <tr>
                  <th>Event title</th>
                  <th>Event location</th> 
               </tr>
               {this.state.data.slice(0,5).map(event => (<tr>
                  <td>{event.title}</td>
                  <td>{event.location}</td>
               </tr>))}
            </table>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
 } 
}

ReactDOM.render(
   <App source=”http://localhost:8888/example/api/events" />, 
   document.getElementById(‘container’)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just would not code it in the above examples like that.

1. I would not use setting variables to `this`  reminds me the old days of angularjs which a lot of people did  `var vm = this`   (vm for view model )
2. Need to be using modern javascript with arrow functions and use `map` and not `forEach`

   > sample below:

   ```
   class App extends React.Component {

       constructor(props) {
           super(props);
           this.state = {
              data: []
           }
       }

       componentDidMount() {

          axios.get(this.props.source)
              .then((event) => { 
                  this.setState({
                      data: event.data
                  });
          })
       }


   render() {
        const yourData = this.state.data.map(item => (
        // notice array so no return here , ( ) instead of { } 
       // notice also map instead of forEach creates a closure - map is preferred
       <tr>
           <td>{item.title}</td> 
           <td>{item.location}</td>
       </tr>
   })
   return (
      <div className=”container”>
           <div className=”row”>
                <div className=”col-md-6 col-md-offset-5">
                    <h1 className=”title”>All Events</h1>
                     <table>
                       <tr>
                          <th>Event title</th>
                           <th>Event location</th> 
                       </tr>
                      {yourData}
                  </table>
                </div>
             </div>
         </div>
        );
      } 
   }

    ReactDOM.render(
      <App source=”http://localhost:8888/example/api/events" />, 
          document.getElementById(‘container’)
    );

    // above obviously works and old way of doing things, and that is for a div id of containter
   // I would setup an api to append to and use the componentDidMount() {... }  
   // then -->   export default App;
   ```