# Returning html from fetch() and showing in to user

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I make API call using `fetch().then()` ...

Getting response using application/json and I want to save data from response inside html tags, return it and show to user.

From API I get 25 results but I want only first 6 (made this by using for loop).

What is inside `console.log()` I want to show in code where is comment "Result should be here".

Can I and how make it happen?

Code is below.

I want to use it in Stateless/Functional Component, so without handling the state.

I'm new in all of this so please be gentle.

```js
const Related = props => {
  const url = `/artist/${props.artistId}/related`;

  const getRelatedArtists = () => {
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        var artist, name, numFans, img;
        for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
          artist = res.data[i];
          name = artist.name;
          numFans = artist.nb_fan;
          img = artist.picture;
          console.log(`
            <div>
              <p>Name: ${name}</p>
              <p>Fans: ${numFans}</p>
              <img src=${img} alt=${name} />
            </div>
          `);
        }
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Related artists</p>
      <button onClick={getRelatedArtists}>get</button>
      {/* Result should be here */}
    </div>
  );
};
```

The result that I want is like this:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In React, how to show data from API in a HTML table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40234757/in-react-how-to-show-data-from-api-in-a-html-table)

Comment: @Sunil thanks for example, but I want to use it without state. If it's possible (?)

Comment: You have to use either state or store. If you are using functional component, then you can dispatch an action to reducer updating your store (when your API call is finished). The store update will re-render the UI with new data. In the newer versions of react, you can you react [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) to achieve the same inside stateless components.

Comment: @Sunil yes, i will try with hooks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React is very *state* and *props* driven - either props are *passed* to a component or state is *maintained* by one internally. In your example, without knowing more detail, it looks like your only option here would be to leverage [component state](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html). That means you can't use a stateless component, at minimum you would be looking at a `PureComponent` or `Component` i.e.

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';

class Related extends PureComponent {
  state = {
    artists: null,
    error: null
  }

  constructor(props) {
    this.super();
    this.url = `/artist/${props.artistId}/related`;
  }

  getRelatedArtists = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch(this.url);
      const json = await res.json();
      this.setState({ artists: json.data, error: null });
    } catch(e) {
      console.error(e);
      this.setState({ error: 'Unable to fetch artists' });
    }
  }

  renderError() {
    if (!this.state.error) return null;

    return (
      <span className="error">{this.state.error}</span>
    )
  }

  renderArtistList() {
    if (!this.state.artists) return null;

    return this.state.artists.map((x,i) => (
      <div key={i}>
        <p>Name: ${x.name}</p>
        <p>Fans: ${x.nb_fans}</p>
        <img src=${x.picture} alt=${name} />
      </div>
    ));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Related artists</p>
        <button onClick={this.getRelatedArtists}>get</button> {this.renderError()}
        {this.renderArtistList()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

If you are using React 16.x, then you should perhaps consider looking at using [Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html). Here's how that would look as a Function component

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react';

function Related(props) {
  // setup state
  const [artists, setArtists] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  // setup click handler
  const getRelatedArtists = useCallback(async () => {
   try {
      // fetch data from API
      const res = await fetch(`/artist/${props.artistId}/related`);
      const json = await res.json();
      // set state
      setArtists(json.data);
      setError(null);
    } catch(e) {
      console.error(e);
      setError('Unable to fetch artists');
    }
  }, [props.artistId]);
  // setup render helper
  function renderArtist(artist, key) {
    return (
      <div key={key}>
        <p>Name: ${artist.name}</p>
        <p>Fans: ${artist.nb_fans}</p>
        <img src=${artist.picture} alt=${artist.name} />
      </div>
    );
  }
  // render component
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Related artists</p>
      <button onClick={getRelatedArtists}>get</button> {error}
      {artists && artists.map(renderArtist)}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Hey @James, thanks for helping.
I include this code with React hooks and got error: Uncaught TypeError: artists.map is not a function.

what now? can you explain it to me?

Comment: @Zrna what does the response from the server look like? I presumed you are receiving a JSON list, but doesn't look like you are.

Comment: @Zrna ah ok, can see the payload isn't quite what I was expecting, looks like you have a paged response. I have updated to suit.

Comment: Man, you are lifesaver for me. **This works**. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

while using react so you need to use the advantages that react provides to you, you should split your code and make it reusable.

secondly: for getting just a few numbers from related posts from a big array you don't need to make a loop you can just declare a variable and store in it the number of posts you need to store in it

```html
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Post from './post/post'

class RelatedPosts extends Component{
    state = {
        realted: [],
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        const url = `/artist/${props.artistId}/related`;
        fetch(url)
            .then(response=>{
                const relatedPosts = response.data.slice(0 ,4),
                    latestRelatedPosts = relatedPosts.map(post=>{
                        return {
                            post
                        }
                    })
                ;
                this.setState({
                    realted: latestRelatedPosts
                });
            }).catch(error=>{
                console.log(error)
            })
    }
    render() {
        let relatedPosts = this.state.realted.map(realtedPost=>{
            return (
                <Post post={realtedPost}/>
            );
        });
        return (
            <section className="Posts">
                <p>Related artists</p>
                {relatedPosts}
            </section>
        );
    }
}
export default RelatedPosts;
```

here I created the request in componentDidMount Lifecycle because it is invoked immediately after a component is inserted into the tree and you can find more information [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)

and here I will create a new component to simplify the code to maintenance later if you want to change anything later and I will pass to it the data which comes from the response of my request

```html
import React from 'react';
const post = (props) => (
    <article className="relatedPost">
        <h1>Name: {props.post.Name}</h1>
        <h1>Fans: {props.post.numFans}</h1>
        <img src={img} alt={name} />
    </article>
);
export default post
```